# Inserting data into the PostgreSQL from Java Servlet

Tags: java, postgresql, servlets

I am trying to use java servlet to input data into the database.

```
package new;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class display extends HttpServlet{
  public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException{
  super.init(config);
  }


  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("command: " + request.getParameter("command"));
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        java.io.PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("<title>Reg</title></head><body>");
        out.println("<h2>REG Form</h2><tr>");

        // HTMl Customer Input
        out.println("<form method=\"post\" action =\""
                + request.getContextPath() + "/display\" >");
        out.println("<table width=\"440\" border=\"0\">");
        out.println("<tr><th width=\"124\" scope=\"row\">Artist Info</th>");
        out.println("<td width=\"150\">Details</td>");
        // First input box: DOB
        out.println("<tr><th scope=\"row\">DOB:</th>");
        out.println("<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"dob\" size=\"20\" ></td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        // Second input box: First Name
        out.println("<tr><th scope=\"row\">Firts name:</th>");
        out.println("<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"firtsname\" size=\"20\" ></td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        // Third input box: Last name
        out.println("<tr><th scope=\"row\">Last name:</th>");
        out.println("<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"lastname\" size=\"20\" ></td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        // Submit button
        out.println("</td></tr><tr><td valign=\"top\">");
        out.println("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Register\"></td></tr>");
        out.println("</table></form>");
        out.println("</body></html>");
    }



  /**Process the HTTP Get request*/


  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Establish variables

        // HTML results
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        java.io.PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("<title>Result</title></head><body>");
        out.println("<h2>Welcome.</h2></br>");


        //Establish Variables for percentages of user input for each state and for each party
        int birthyear=0;
        String familyname = null, givenname = null;

        //DOB
        if (request.getParameter("birthyear").equals(""))   {
            out.println("Input date of birth");
        //otherwise, get the input
    }   else    {
        birthyear = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("birthyear"));
    }

        if (request.getParameter("familyname").equals(""))  {
            out.println("Input first name");

    }   else    {
        familyname = request.getParameter("familyname");
    }

        if (request.getParameter("givenname").equals(""))   {
            out.println("Input last name");

    }   else    {
        givenname = request.getParameter("givenname");
    }


  Connection connection=null;

  int id = 0;
  int agentid = id++;

  try {
  // Load the database driver
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/caglar", "postgres",
                "6666yyy");
   //Add the data into the database
  String sql = "insert into agent values (?,?,?,?)";
  PreparedStatement pst = 
  connection.prepareStatement(sql);
  pst.setInt(1, agentid);
  pst.setInt(2, birthyear);
  pst.setString(3, familyname);
  pst.setString(4, givenname);

   }
  catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
  out.println("Couldn't load database driver: " 
  + e.getMessage());
  }
  catch(SQLException e){
  out.println("SQLException caught: " 
  + e.getMessage());
  }
  catch (Exception e){
  out.println(e);
  }
  finally {
  // Always close the database connection.
  try {
  if (connection != null) connection.close();
  }
  catch (SQLException ignored){
  out.println(ignored);
  }
  }
  }
}
```

I get the following error in doPost:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    S517.display.doPost(display.java:73)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Does anybody know why?? I simply want to add data into the db using a servlet. Driver exist in the library.

line 73 & 74

```
    if (request.getParameter("birthyear").equals(""))   {
        out.println("Input date of birth");
```

Comment: Could you point out line 73 to us? That would be a little easier

Comment: 73 if (request.getParameter("birthyear").equals("")) {
74   out.println("Input date of birth");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is  on line 73:

```
birthyear = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("birthyear"));
```

I'm guessing by your code that the form in the doGet function is the form posting the data you want to store in your database. Your form doesn't contain a birthyear field. Its absence makes request.getParameter("birthyear") return null, which causes a NullPointerException when trying to parse an int from it.

Furthermore, you should not only prepare your statement, but execute it as well:

```
PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setInt(1, agentid);
pst.setInt(2, birthyear);
pst.setString(3, familyname);
pst.setString(4, givenname);

// add this line
pst.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Oh right, doGet did not have that :S but now, it does not actually add any values to the database, any clues?

Comment: I just noticed that you prepare your statement, but never really execute it :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out and giving the solution!! Now my other question is about agentid. How do I make it automatically increase each time?

Comment: I can use ++counter method but how about reading that from the previous entry and adding up? how can I do it?

Comment: In PostgreSQL you can create a sequence (see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createsequence.html) for doing this. Then, for inserting id values, use nextval('your_sequence')

Comment: @verhage: If you also set the DEFAULT of the column to `nextval('your_sequence')`, you can ignore it completely and it will be assigned automatically (or use the key word `DEFAULT` in INSERT statements). A `serial` column is just that: an `integer` with an attached sequence. If you need the assigned value back, use the RETURNING clause of an INSERT statement.